# File size and type for download links on website?

Tags: hyperlinks, download

The new website I'm building has a section for the company newsletter (and on a sub-page, a newsletter archive which spans back to 2002). The newsletters are displayed in a table (ignore the names, they're in the process of being renamed) along with the type of file and the size. This list is auto-generated from a folder on the server and users may be browsing the site on their mobile phone.

Some people are saying that the file size and type shouldn't be shown because we live in the age of high speed internet and more-than-capable devices. I'm happy to ditch the `type` column because all the files are PDF, but the file sizes vary from 44kb to 9mb, and I feel it's good UX to show the user the size so they can know how long they'd need to wait if their device decides to open rather than download the file, and if the amount of data it would require would fit their current usage limits (in Australia, some phone plans have 100mb of data unless you pay extra)

How would you approach this both on the page that has about 24 items on it, and on the archive page which has ~300 items (split up by year, and is an important part of the history of the company)?

[image: Newsletter Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always important to show the filetype. Users are apprehensive about downloading unknown files(EXE files etc.)

With regard to the file size, make it readable. 4.2MB instead of 4,268KB.

You could make it like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd much prefer a one-line summary of the contents of each newsletter, or at least a title, compared to type of file. To show file size, you could display sizes just next to the name and only in cases where the file sizes are larger than a certain threshold, such as 2 or 4 MB.